# Converting character to number of months

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset, where there is a column- account_age. In this column, the age is mentioned in format- "1YRS 5MON" in character form.
How to convert the same to month ? Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do match of the 'YRS', 'MON' with `gsubfn`, replace the characters with the numbers and `eval`uate

```
library(gsubfn)
unname(sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]+", list(YRS = "*12 +", MON = "*1"),
           df1$col1), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
#[1] 17
```

---

Or another option is to extract the digits and do a sum or products

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dbl(str_extract_all(df1$col1, "\\d+"), ~ as.numeric(.x) %*% c(12, 1))
#[1] 17
```

---

Or we can remove the letters, read it with data.frame and get the sum of products

```
as.matrix(read.table(text = gsub("[A-Z]+", "", df1$col1),
       header = FALSE) )%*% c(12, 1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = "1YRS 5MON", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hello. Yes it is working. How to apply it to the entire column. The dataset name is full and column is col1. Kindly guide

Comment: @AjeeteshMishra  INstead of `str1`, you need `df1$col1`.  BTW, if the column is `factor`, then convert it to `character` in `as.character(df1$col1)`